# Terraform: How to associate multiple subnet to route table?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform v.0.11.7.

I wants to create 4 subnets (2 public subnets, 2 private subnets)

Here's a content of vars.tf

```
variable "region" {
  default = "ap-south-1"
}

variable "ami_id" {
  type = "map"
  default = "ami-d783a9b8"
}

variable "credentials" {
  default = "/root/.aws/credentials"
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "pub_subnet_aza_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.10.0/24"
}

variable "pub_subnet_azc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.20.0/24"
}

variable "pri_subnet_aza_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.30.0/24"
}

variable "pri_subnet_azc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.40.0/24"
}
```

Now inside main.tf, i want to associate the first 2 public subnets to public route table, how to do that?

```
resource "aws_subnet" "pub_subnet_aza" {
  vpc_cidr = "{aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.pub_subnet_aza_cidr}"
  tags {
    Name = "Pub-Sunet-A"
 }
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zone.available.name[0]}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pub_subnet_azc" {
  vpc_cidr = "{aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.pub_subnet_azc_cidr}"
  tags {
   Name = "Pub-Subnet-C"
}
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zone.available.name[2]}"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.pub_subnet_aza.id}"  # How to put pub_subnet_azc.id into here?
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
}
```

Comment: Better use lists of subnets to reduce the amount of variables (we started at work in the same way and it's a mess..). Then you can also use `count = length(var.subnets)` to get 2 instances of the route table association resource and pick the correct one from the subnets list.

Comment: @StephenKing You should add this as an answer and provide a worked example.

Comment: Not from mobile ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Better use lists of subnets to reduce the amount of variables. Then you can also use `count = length(var.subnets)` to get 2 instances of the route table association resource and pick the correct one from the subnets list.

```
variable "subnet_cidrs_public" {
  description = "Subnet CIDRs for public subnets (length must match configured availability_zones)"
  # this could be further simplified / computed using cidrsubnet() etc.
  # https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#cidrsubnet-iprange-newbits-netnum-
  default = ["10.0.10.0/24", "10.0.20.0/24"]
  type = "list"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_cidrs_public)}"

  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.subnet_cidrs_public[count.index]}"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zones[count.index]}"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_cidrs_public)}"

  subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
}
```

I see you've been reading availability zones via `data`, which is fine and you can still do. You just have to somehow set the association between a subnet and the AZ. I leave that up to you.

Certainly more elegant would be to provision a subnet in every AZ of that region. Once we use [`cidrsubnet()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#cidrsubnet-iprange-newbits-netnum-) to compute address spaces for the subnets, we could use `length(data.availability_zones)` as the driver for all the rest. Shouldn't be too complex.

Here is the full code:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

variable "availability_zones" {
  description = "AZs in this region to use"
  default = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1c"]
  type = "list"
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "subnet_cidrs_public" {
  description = "Subnet CIDRs for public subnets (length must match configured availability_zones)"
  # this could be further simplified / computed using cidrsubnet() etc.
  # https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#cidrsubnet-iprange-newbits-netnum-
  default = ["10.0.10.0/24", "10.0.20.0/24"]
  type = "list"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  tags {
    Name = "stackoverflow-51739482"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_cidrs_public)}"

  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.subnet_cidrs_public[count.index]}"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zones[count.index]}"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  tags {
    Name = "public"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_cidrs_public)}"

  subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks bro.